# A word denoting something taking place for the last time in an indefinitely large series

Tags: word-request, register, numerals, ordinals

I've been looking for the word denoting something taking place for the latest time in an indefinitely large series, for example, the solar eclipse occurring for the______ th(?) time from the beginning of the World.

Being aware of the words "umpteenth" and "umptieth", both meaning coming after all others in an indefinitely numerous series, I'm not sure they perfectly match the idea of repetition of the event for only god knows what time.  Asking this, I bear in mind that suffixes "-teenth" and "-ties" in ordinal numerals are used to form those either from 13 to 19 or tens from 20 to 90. So is there a *single* word/common expression to comply with my request?

Comment: gazillionth? :-)

Comment: @Karolini - A good one for an infinite number, but I mean something that might be technically counted, at least very approximately--tens of hundreds or thousands, maybe millions...

Comment: Well, then maybe nth.

Comment: @Karolini Why not post your answer?

Comment: When you say "last" there is confusion over whether you mean "final" (which is the word I would use if you do) or simply the "latest" (which is the most common English word for the concept). You seem to like the answer "nth" which means you're looking not for a common expression, but something "mathematical."

Comment: @JasonBassford I absolutely agree. Editing..

Comment: So, you're looking for a word that can serve the purpose of (say) "first" in "a solar eclipse occurred today for the first time ever", except that instead of meaning the earliest one, it means the most recent one so far? Is that correct?

Comment: @TannerSwett -- I mean the latest but not the last time, and the cardinal number is very, very big yet unknown-- maybe the hundredth, maybe the millionth time when something reoccurs.

Comment: Do you have a word in your own native language which means *the-most-recent-in-an-ongoing-series-of-indeterminate-length*?

Comment: And are you looking for a mathematical term? A colloquialism?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo In my mother tongue, I'd say what may be translated into English as "for god knows which (or what--I'm not sure) time". Re your second comment, I'm looking for a common word for the cardinal far more higher than the hundredth or even thousandth time when something reoccurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use **nth** to mean an unspecified position in a sequence. For example:

- the **nth** element in a list
- It's the **nth** time I've explained it to you.

Comment: Although **nth** is suitable, I'm not sure that it works as well with spoken language as it does with written language.  I think **umpteenth** or **gazillionth** might work better.

Comment: According to the dictionaries I've looked up the suggested"nth" in, so far it seems to be the word I've been looking for. I'll wait a bit for other possible suggestions, and unless there appears something more helpful, I'll gladly accept your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should really add a [dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nth) for this to your answer. It would indicate that you have objective evidence for your claim, and that it's actually recognized as a word.

Comment: @Rompey: **nth** is not the word you've described.  I'm with EllieK on this.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo All the answers and comments taken into account, to me my problem seems to have been solved. My special thanks to Elliek.

Comment: @Rompey:  I'm glad it seems solved to you,  you can proceed to misuse it. But *nth* does not connote "god knows how many" and it is not " a common word for the cardinal far more higher than the hundredth or even thousandth time when something reoccurs".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: It's not that I'm going to take this word to my active writing, let alone conversational, English vocabulary--recognizing it in a text would be quite enough for me. Besides, the times when I learned new words by their definitions alone, has long passed: Vocabulary.com has been providing me with a plethora of examples of the usage from the times I'd had the internet connection. According to that source, even if you might encounter with "nth" in books, it'll be once in every 24,270 pages you've read. So I really have no more problems with that word. Thanks for your concern, though.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @EllieK in a comment, [**umpteenth**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/umpteenth) is a legitimate word, which means essentially the same thing:

> very many : indefinitely numerous
>
> Hundreds of companies create data about people on the internet from Google to *umpteen* obscure little companies.
>
> "Umpteen" usually describes an indefinite and large number or amount, while the related "umpteenth" is used for the latest or last in an indefinitely numerous series.
>
> Origin and Etymology of umpteen
>   blend of *umpty* (such and such) and *-teen* (as in *thirteen*)

When discussing *writing*, Google Ngram Viewer shows that *nth* is [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nth%2C%20umpteenth&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cnth%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnth%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cumpteenth%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bumpteenth%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUmpteenth%3B%2Cc0) than *umpteen*, but I suspect that *umpteen* is more common in informal speech. (If I heard somebody say *nth* in a bar, I'd stare at them oddly; if I heard them say *umpteenth*, I might grin but I wouldn't find it strange.) So, it would depend on context which to use.

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for is **latest** (you cannot mean **last**  as you say in your title, if the series is of indeterminate length).

**Latest** implies that there have been more than one to date, and that there will probably be others to follow.

> In his latest tweet, ...
>
> This latest eruption was orders of magnitude more powerful than those preceding it.